# How to fix Trojan:EC2/DGADomainRequest.B

Tags: 20.04, amazon-ec2, malware

I have an EC2 instance which had some WordPress websites. My Ubuntu version is 20.04. A few days ago they were affected by malware and I have removed all malware from these websites, but in my AWS GuardDuty, it's giving an error: `Trojan:EC2/DGADomainRequest.B`. How can I fix it?

Here are the details.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]